# Oauth 2.0 Client Credentials - Custom Auth Provider

Tags: oauth2, auth-provider, open-id-connect, salesforce-connect, auth

I am building out a Salesforce Connect customer adapter to translate rest responses into external data objects.

To authenticate these requests, I would like to use ***Oauth 2.0's client credentials flow*** as a custom auth provider.

While developing the AuthProviderPlugin, I am running into two roadblocks, the required `initiate` and `getUserInfo` methods.

For the initiate method I am required to return a page reference, but since this is a client credentials flow, I do not need a user to login, I only need to provide the client id, client secret, and access token url.

> For the client crendentials flow, what page reference should I return
>   if I do not need a user to login?

I know I need to get the token, but it looks like that should be handled in the `handleCallBack` method.

For the `getUserInfo` method, I do not have or need user info, I am simply looking to create an auth provider using Oauth 2.0's client credentials flow to use in my Salesforce Connect Adapter.

> Can I return an empty Auth.UserData object back to satisfy the
>   required return?

Lastly...

> To me it appears the AuthProviderPluginClass and it's custom adapters
>   do not support Oauth 2.0's client credentials flow by design... is
>   this true? If so, what would be the recommended approach to unattended
>   authentication? Open Id Connect?

Code In Progress:

```
global class myAuthProvider extends Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass {

  // Use this URL for the endpoint that the 
  // authentication provider calls back to for configuration.
  // *****Where do I need to redirect to?*****
  public String redirectUrl = 'https://REDIRECTWHERE?.COM'; 
  private String clientId;
  private String secret;

  // Application redirection to the website for 
  // authentication and authorization.
  //*****How is this different from the accessTokenUrl?*****
  private String authUrl;  

  // URI to get the new access token
  private String accessTokenUrl; 

  // Api name for the custom metadata type created for this auth provider.
  private String customMetadataTypeApiName = 'myMetaDataApiName'; 

  // Api URL to access the user
  // *****I do need to access the user.*****
  private String userAPIUrl; 

  // Version of the user api URL to access data
  // *****I do not need user data.***** 
  private String userAPIVersionUrl; 

  global String getCustomMetadataType() {
      return customMetadataTypeApiName;
  } 

  global PageReference initiate(Map<string,string> 
    authProviderConfiguration, String stateToPropagate) 
    { 

        clientId = authProviderConfiguration.get('Client_Id__c'); 
        secret = authProviderConfiguration.get('Client_Secret__c'); 
        accessTokenUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('Access_Token_Url_c');

        String url = accessTokenUrl + '?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + secret + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUrl;
        //*****Where do I need to redirect to since this is a client credentials flow, not a user login flow?*****
        return new PageReference(url); 

    } 

    global Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse handleCallback(Map<string,string> 
    authProviderConfiguration, Auth.AuthProviderCallbackState state ) 
    { 
        // Here, the developer will get the callback with actual protocol. 
        // Their responsibility is to return a new object called 
        // AuthProviderTokenResponse. 
        // This will contain an optional accessToken and refreshToken 
        clientId = authProviderConfiguration.get('Client_Id__c'); 
        secret = authProviderConfiguration.get('Client_Secret__c'); 
        accessTokenUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('Access_Token__c'); 

        Http http = new Http();
        httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');

        String url = accessTokenUrl;
        request.setEndpoint(url); 

        request.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + secret);
        request.setMethod('POST');

        HttpResponse res = new httpResponse();
        system.debug(request);
        res = http.send(request);
        string getTokenString = res.getBody();
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(getTokenString);
        string getToken;
        getToken = String.valueOf(results.get('access_token'));

        //*****What if I do not receive/need a refresh token, non-expiring token*****
        return new Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse('myAuthProvider', getToken, 
        'refreshToken', getToken); 
    } 

    //*****I do not need user data, but a UserData Object must be returned. Can I compile with blank data?*****
    global Auth.UserData getUserInfo(Map<string,string> 
    authProviderConfiguration, 
    Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse response) 
    { 
        //Here the developer is responsible for constructing an 
        //Auth.UserData object 
        String token = response.oauthToken; 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        userAPIUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('API_User_Url__c');
        userAPIVersionUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get
        ('API_User_Version_Url__c'); 
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + token); 
        req.setEndpoint(userAPIUrl); 
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        req.setMethod('GET'); 

        Http http = new Http(); 
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req); 
        String responseBody = res.getBody(); 
        String id = '';
        String fname = ''; 
        String lname = ''; 
        String flname = ''; 
        String uname = ''; 
        String locale = ''; 
        Map<String,String> provMap = new Map<String,String>(); 
        return new Auth.UserData(id, fname, lname, flname, uname, 'what', locale, null, 'myAuthProvider', null, provMap); 
    } 


}
```

This related questions appears to support the statement that AuthProviderPluginClass does not support the client credentials flow, but I may be misinterpreting: [Custom Auth Provider usage for unattended OAuth flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164030/custom-auth-provider-usage-for-unattended-oauth-flow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a custom authprovider which I've shared "as-is" on Github.
It implements both the Client Credentials and JWT Bearer variant (without a certificate).  Feel free to fork from it.
https://github.com/bobbywhitesfdc/ApigeeAuthProvider

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro, using this as a template i was able to write both auth and refresh_token logic

Comment: Your Apigee custom AuthProvider was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a template for custom auth provider method using client assertion JWT instead with ECDSA algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce Premier Support has stated:

> The Custom Auth provider set up in Salesforce would not allow you to
>   enter client credentials and login.

The two posts below also confirm this:

[Custom Auth Provider usage for unattended OAuth flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164030/custom-auth-provider-usage-for-unattended-oauth-flow)

[Named Credentials and support for the OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant Type and alternatives](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225121/named-credentials-and-support-for-the-oauth2-client-credentials-grant-type-and-a?noredirect=1&lq=1)

As a solution to the problem, I added the token callout and pass into the data connection method for the Custom Salesforce Connect adapter. ***However, I believe it may be better to run a scheduled process every X minutes to update the token in an encrypted custom setting to limit the token callouts.***

Referencing DataSourceConnection Class Documentation: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_Connection.htm

```
global class SampleDataSourceConnection extends DataSource.Connection {

        private String EXTERNAL_SRC_URL = 'https://myEndPoint.com/rest-service/comments';
        private final String COL_HEADER_DISPLAYURL = 'DisplayUrl';
        private final String COL_HEADER_COMMENTTITLE = 'CommentTitle';
        private final String COL_HEADER_COMMENTBODY = 'CommentBody';
        private final String COL_HEADER_EXTERNAL_ID = 'ExternalId';
        private string getToken;

        global SampleDataSourceConnection(DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionParams) {
                Http http = new Http();
                httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                request.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
                request.setEndPoint('https://myEndpoint.com/token');
                request.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myClientId&client_secret=myClientSecret);
                request.setMethod('POST'); HttpResponse res = new httpResponse();
                res = http.send(request); 
                string getTokenString = res.getBody();
                Map < String, Object > results = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(getTokenString); 
                getToken = String.valueOf(results.get('access_token')); system.debug(getToken); 
                System.debug(res.getBody());
                }

                override global List < DataSource.Table > sync() {
                        ....
```

Comment: The statement "The Custom Auth provider set up in Salesforce would not allow you to enter client credentials and login." is factually incorrect.  See my answer where I link to custom authprovider that does exactly that :-)

Comment: @BobbyWhite, there seems to be consensus that it is not appropriate to store consumer key and secret in a custom metadata type due to security concerns, but since getCustomMetaDataType is required by the AuthPluginProviderClass that seems to contradict this?

Comment: If one is concerned about the safety of the keys, you could encrypt/decrypt it using some secret, but that hasn't been a show stopper so far.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to bypass the mandatory PageReference, you could redirect directly to the callback url created in your Auth Provider, example:

```
global PageReference initiate(Map<string,string> authProviderConfiguration, String stateToPropagate) {
    new PageReference('https://....my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/YOURAUTHPROVIDER?state=' + stateToPropagate);
}
```

This way, the Salesforce Admin will never notice he got redirected.

Then, for the getUserInfo, you can bypass it by returning dummy data, such as:

```
    global Auth.UserData getUserInfo(Map<string,string> authProviderConfiguration, Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse response) {
        return new Auth.UserData('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo foo', 'uname',
                                 'what', 'en', null, 'YOURAUTHPROVIDER', null, new Map<String,String>());
    }
```

Then, in the handleCallback method you can make a HTTPRequest to your authentication endpoint using a Named Credential to store the Client Id/Secret in a Named Principal / Username-Password.

I hope this help.

Comment: Going to give this a shot and report back, this looks promising and if it works will mark as the correct answer.