# Can a user logged in to one org be moved to a logged in session in another org?

Tags: login, session, digital-experience, multi-org

This question relates to a situation where some data is not replicated across the orgs making moving the user's interactive session between the orgs seem like a possible approach. The UI is a Digital Experience, and whatever admin in both orgs is needed could be done.

So:

- User logs in to org A
- For a particular Digital Experience page they are transferred to org B without needing to login again
- They are then transferred back to org A

Or is it necessary/cleaner to keep the session tied to org A, and make explicit REST calls to org B from the org A session?

Comment: SSO from org A to org B?

Comment: Hi @identigral, Maybe. So login to A, go to a URL on B, and if the user has a license on B (as well as A) and both orgs are configured for SSO, then the transitions are invisible to the user?

Comment: Yes. SAML out of the box or custom via [SamlJitHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm) supports just-in-time provisioning. if you go with that, you don't need to do any setup on the other side..best case. SAML is not invisible tho. Invisible SSO that is not SAML and secure would mean you proxying all requests via backend and custom front-end. Invisible SSO that is not SAML and insecure - you retrieve the session ID via any means necessary and then use that for access to org B.

Comment: Thanks @identigral. The just-in-time is only available using SAML, and not for OAUTH?

Comment: oAuth - out of the box the user provisioning is an [async flow tied to the connected app](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_user_provisioning.htm&type=5). You might be thinking of provisioning as a side-effect with [custom AuthProvider](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164030/custom-auth-provider-usage-for-unattended-oauth-flow). Both of these options have a lot of pitfalls, SAML is the best way to go.